# Google Login: Getting User information with play services

Tags: android, google-play, backend, deprecated, google-signin

I am working on an android game where I have to get the users gmail address for the back-end.  I am using the game helper class that google provides and am using the google play API and well as the plus api.  Until recently I have used

`Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(_gameHelper.getApiClient());`

In order to get the address, but the this code is depreciated so I can not user it on certain devices.

I have tried getting the information from the information from `onActivityResult` from the login but the Intent returns as null.  Not only that but to access that information from the Intent I require the google sign in API which will not function with the play API.  I would appreciate any help or suggestions on this matter.  Thank You very much in advance.

Comment: Deprecated is entirely different from 'not working' - it certainly does work on all devices.

Comment: Please read http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html to see if it can help you or not

Answer (score 0):

Add Google Sign-In to Your Android App

Configure Google Sign-In:

```
// Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic profile. ID and
// basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestEmail()
    .build();

// Build a GoogleApiClient with access to GoogleSignIn.API and the options above.
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this, this)
    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
    .build();
```

Then, when the sign-in button is clicked, start the sign-in intent:

```
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

The user is prompted to select a Google account to sign in with. If you requested scopes beyond profile, email, and openid, the user is also prompted to grant access to the requested resources.

Finally, handle the activity result:

```
@Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from
    //   GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            // Get account information
            mFullName = acct.getDisplayName();
            mEmail = acct.getEmail();
        }
    }
}
```

See: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/

Comment: You can't use that with Google Play Games.

Comment: I agree I tried that method before and it came across the capatability issue.   I am looking for a way to get the login info with google play

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it in Kotlin in the current version:

```
Games.getPlayersClient(requireContext(), GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(requireContext())!!)
            .currentPlayer
            .addOnSuccessListener { player ->
                
            }
```

Comment: Please don't just write/paste codes. Explanation should be there even if the code is pretty straight forward.